# Update image in imshow()?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am attempting to display an image over time as it is transformed by a function. I use `imshow()` to display my image.

If I use the code,

```
im = zeros(y,x);

for n=...
   im = im + myFunction(...);
   imshow(im)
end
```

then, each iteration of the image is correctly displayed. The problem is the figure shown is very small. If I attempt to adjust the figure while the script is running, as soon as the next iteration of the for loop is reached, the image resets to its original size.

I would like to be able to resize the display and keep it with my desired size and location on-screen.

The documentation for `imshow()` states,

> 'Parent' — Parent axes of image object
> Axes object | UIAxes object
> Parent axes of image object, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'Parent' and an Axes object or a UIAxes object. Use the 'Parent' name-value argument to build a UI that gives you control of the Figure and Axes properties.

The other questions related to this problem online point to using a set axes. My attempt at using an axes is below.

```
figure
ha = axes('units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
im = zeros(y,x);
imshow(im, 'Parent', ha);

for n=...
    im = im + myFunction(...);
    imshow(im, 'Parent', ha);
end
```

This code does not work. For some reason, the figure is not displayed until after the for loop has completed. Despite the fact that the initial imshow call is before the for loop even starts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the size if your image does not change iteration to iteration, one option would be to set the CData property of the graphics Image object returned by imshow.

```
 hIm = imshow(im, 'Parent', ha);
 
 for n=...
      im = im + myFunction(...);
      hIm.CData = im;
      drawnow limitrate
 end
```

Comment: That seems to be the smart way to approach it. I found that it still didn't work with the code you provided. It would only pull up an image after the for loop finished execution. By adding a `pause` inside the loop, the image updating did work. I put the pause at an infeasibly low number, `pause( 0.00000000000000000000000000001)` and it worked so I guess there was some issue with timing needed to update the `imshow`?

Comment: I dont' think pause is what you want to force rendering. I'd try:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html

drawnow limitrate